# Writing 3 integers to a file and restoring them back using fprintf and fscanf

Tags: c

I write 3 integers to a file using the following calls to `fprintf`:

```
FILE* fid = fopen("c:\\a.bin", "wb");    
a = fprintf(fid, "%d", 2);
b = fprintf(fid, "%d", 576);
c = fprintf(fid, "%d", 5);
fclose(fid);
```

Then I try to read 3 integers back using the following calls:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 0;
FILE* fid = fopen("c:\\a.bin", "rb");
fscanf(fid, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
```

After calling `fscanf` the values of a, b and c are 25765, 0 and 0, respectively. How can I restore my numbers back? Why the calls to `fprintf` writes only 5 bytes rather than 12?

Comment: Delimiter is required.

Comment: Can you show your code which is used to read from file..?

Comment: 1. you probably meant "... calls to `fprintf`...";

2. you probably need to open file for writing, not binary writing, so use `"w"` instead of `"wb"`;

3. `fscanf` always returns a single integer and it's a check-for-error code. You better post the code for reading from file, so we can help you.

Comment: The file is called `a.bin` - do you want to write a binary file with raw data? Then use `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: Do you really mean this to be a binary file? Or a text file?

Comment: 1) Text: Open with `"w"` and `"r"` and use `fprintf(fid, " %d", ...);`  (space added) **or** 2 Binary: use `int a = 2; fwrite(&a, sizeof a, 1, fid)` and `fread(&a, sizeof a, 1, fid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write binary integers, you shouldn't use `fprintf()`, which is for *printing*, i.e. transforming in-memory data into human-readable form.

You should just do some `fwrite()`s, i.e.:

```
const int two = 2;

fwrite(&two, sizeof two, 1, fid);
```

And then read back using `fread()`, from a file opened for binary read of course. Also, check the return value(s) of I/O call(s).